# Android GCM onRegistered not called

Tags: java, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I've got a problem to get token from my google developper account.
The GCM method onRegistered from my class GcmIntentService is not called...

This is my source code :

Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.gcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.test.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.test.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.test.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my GcmIntentService.java :

```
package com.test.gcm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GcmIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
    public GcmIntentService(String senderId) {
        super("************");
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", senderId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("token", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`onRegistered` is not called because you don't have `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` in your receiver's intent filter.

It should be :

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.test.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

That's assuing that you are using the old registration method (`GCMRegistrar.register`).

If you are using the new registration method (`GoogleCloudMessaging.register`), you don't need the `onReceive` method, since you would get the registration ID synchronously when you call `register`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've added this line, but this does not solve my problem :/. I would to succeed to get a token with this solution if it's possible.
If I understand the onRegistered method is call when I call the GCMRegistrar.register method ?

This is my new Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.gcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />   

    <permission
        android:name="com.test.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.test.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.test.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.